# Credit card changed by card company: Why is Citi changing my Visa dividend platinum select card to dividend world Mastercard?

Tags: credit-card, reward-program, mastercard, citi, visa

My citi divident platinum select card is being replaced with citi dividend world mastercard.

I don't quite understand their explanation. But what are the changes on the benefits?

why change from visa to mastercard? I think visa is more popularly acceptable. Is this true?

Thanks and regards!

---

Besides the change from Visa to Mastercard, overall, is this move good or bad to customers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of thing happens a lot in the credit card industry.  The bank (Citi) tries to get the best deal they can for themselves.  My guess is Mastercard is charging Citi less fees than Visa was willing to charge them so they switched.  Your only real option is to close your account and switch to a different card that is a Visa.  But I don't think there is a big difference between Visa and Mastercard.  Most are accepted just about everywhere.

It also could be related to the fact that Citi owns a big portion of Mastercard (source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MasterCard)).  So Citi would rather give their business to a company they own instead of Visa.

Comment: One difference I noticed recently is that Visa allows minimum charges, up to $10, but Mastercard still does not. http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/how-do-credit-card-companies-make-profit/2690#2690

Comment: @George: in terms of minimum charges, which one is better then? I do sometimes only buy some small items cost less than 10 dollars.

Comment: @Tim.  The way I read that is Visa is allowing the merchant to force a minimum purchase to allow using their card.  Mastercard will not let the merchant.  So from that standpoint Mastercard is more consumer friendly.

Comment: @tim What mpenrow said.

Comment: @Tim That is moot in the USA at least, as federal law now lets merchants decide if they want a minimum purchase price to use a card.